# Is it possible to do a Babel "scope rename" excluding certain node types?

Tags: babeljs

I am working on a Babel plugin that is rebinding (using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)) some imports which means that I need to create a new variable to point to the new binding since imports are read-only. After that, I want to do a `nodePath.scope.rename` from the original import name to the new "hijacked" variable. This works fine but the problem is that the original imports also get renamed since they are in the global scope.

Is there a way to do the `nodePath.scope.rename` while excluding nodes of type `ImportDeclaration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Binding solution**

Instead of renaming everything in the global scope, we can only rename the bindings, which excludes the original node by scoping to its parent object:

```
const binding = matchingNodePath.scope.getBinding(currentName);

binding.referencePaths.forEach((referencePath) => {
  referencePath.scope.rename(
    currentName,
    hijackedNamespace,
    referencePath.parent
  );
});
```

**Node replace solution**

I could not find any way to exclude import declarations while doing a `scope.rename`. So what I ended up doing is cloning the nodes first:

```
// Get all import declarations.
const importDeclarationNodePaths = (nodePath.get('body') as NodePath[]).filter((node) =>
  node.isImportDeclaration()
) as NodePath<ImportDeclaration>[];

// Make a copy of the node so we can restore it later after we rename all matching variables.
const originalImportDeclarationNodes = importDeclarationNodePaths.map((nodePath) => {
  return cloneNode(nodePath.node, true);
}) as ImportDeclaration[];
```

Then we can rename and restore back the original specifiers

```
nodePath.scope.rename('originalName', 'newName');

// Because of the global scope rename, we need to set back original import declarations.
for (const importPosition in importDeclarationNodePaths) {
  const hijackedImportDeclarationNodePath = importDeclarationNodePaths[importPosition];
  const originalImportDeclarationNode = originalImportDeclarationNodes[importPosition];

  // Replace the specifiers of the hijacked import declaration with its original value.
  hijackedImportDeclarationNodePath.replaceWith(
    importDeclaration(
      originalImportDeclarationNode.specifiers,
      hijackedImportDeclarationNodePath.node.source
    )
  );
}
```